# R- loop to create non-reciprocal ratios of all variables in data frame

Tags: r

Given data arranged in a data frame like this:

```
x1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2<-c(10,9,8,7,6)
x3<-c(9,2,8,3,7)
x4<-c(2,5,3,4,8)
data<-data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

I want to write a loop that will ratio each variable using a previous variable.  The output should look like this:

```
r_x2_x1<-x2/x1
r_x3_x1<-x3/x1
r_x4_x1<-x4/x1
r_x3_x2<-x3/x2
r_x4_x2<-x4/x2
r_x4_x3<-x4/x3
ratios<-data.frame(r_x2_x1, r_x3_x1, r_x4_x1, r_x3_x2, r_x4_x2, r_x4_x3)
```

I want write a loop that will ratio the variables in the order shown above  and work regardless of the number of variables in the dataframe.  I also want the output column names to include some indication of what variables were used in the process (i.e. r_x2_x1 is the standard format I use to say ratio of 2/1).  The variables will not always be x1, x2, x3; they can be any number (usually paired with an x).

I have written simple "for i in..." loops before, but I have no idea where to even start with this.  I think there should be a way to say "start with this variable, divide it into the remaining variables, write a dataframe", but I don't know how to limit it to non-reciprocal ratios only (i.e. if I have x2/x1. I don't need x1/x2).  It is important to limit it as well as some of these sets have as many as 18-20 variables.  It would waste a lot of time to fish through the data sets for only the ratios I need if it included all possible ratios.

I really appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `combn` to create the pairwise combinations of columns, divide, keep it in a `list` and then `cbind` the `list` elements together with `do.call`

```
res <- do.call(cbind, combn(data, 2, FUN= function(x) list(x[2]/x[1])))
names(res) <- combn(names(data), 2, FUN = function(x) paste(x[2], x[1], sep="_"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know about the combn command, so this was very helpful.  The only problem I have now is that the result data frame only includes the numerator of the ratio and doesn't indicate which variable was used as the denominator.  It is in the order I expect (i.e. I know what the ratio is), but I need to find a way to rename the new variables by both the numerator and denominator of the ratio.

Comment: @JenniferMartin  Updated the post

Comment: Great, thanks so much for replying.  It seems that combn is going to be a handy addition to my tollbox.  Thanks again!